# How to configure the search bar above quicklinks?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results, content-search-web-part

I'd like to set a specific content type to be the only type that gives results when you use the search bar above the quick links.

Do I simply go to Site Settings and change the Search Query Rules? Sorry if this is a basic question.

EDIT: Actually, what I really want to do is exclude a specific content type from showing up in search. Allowing other types of content is fine, but there's a specific content type that I plan to use for archive purposes that I'd like to exclude from searches to avoid clutter with multiple of the same item name.

[image]